# Dúvida com FindOne no AngularJS usando MongoJS erro na hora da procura

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Olá estou tentando fazer uma busca no banco com este código utilizando o findOne do mongojs, segue código:

```
 app.get('/detalhesContato/:id', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contatos.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc)    {
     console.log(err);
      res.json(doc);

});
```

`console.log(id)` trás o id correto porém na hora de utilizar a função do `findOne` da este erro:

> "567a16ba28dee028f4a8ad78 <-- console log do id
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined
>       at /Users/Michel/Documents/AngularProjects/RodrigoBranasListaTelefonica/server.js:48:12"

Comment: Já verifiquei tudo no banco a collection tudo correto o id também existe

Comment: O model está sendo carregado antes deste controller?